# Is pure ADA put in a script address locked up forever?

Tags: plutus, cardano-cli

I was trying out the 'always succeeds' script from the helios tutorial
(https://github.com/Hyperion-BT/Helios/blob/main/doc/tutorial_03-always_succeeds.md)
and made a mistake in the change address, so now all my funds (29281.95 ADA) ended up at the script-address:

```
addr_test1wpqdgpwgv7494dmuv2tzl09fwc6alyq4u08fgs45aryn3hc5r25st         | = 29311.37 |
* ba437386485a977b345f081fe8d39435947bf4c6851f87ab4bb6731127503f7b#0    | +     2.00 | Pure Ada
* ba437386485a977b345f081fe8d39435947bf4c6851f87ab4bb6731127503f7b#1    | +     1.14 | Datum
* c161c40f48aa036635fc054990ef7dd42eb5a9d954a176aed482abb2c0846c61#0    | + 29281.95 | Greatest Pure Ada
* c3fef0e132089ae508ce7e557fe804613bee7ca2ee7f29dc569a3fe633f111a7#0    | +     2.00 | Pure Ada
..
..
```

Is there a way to get back the value from the pure Ada tx'es?  (ie. the ones without a datum)

Because this is a script-address, I don't have any .skey for it, and I have the impression
you can only get out the ADA from the tx'es that have a datum.

Is there a way?

*For the record: MAGIC = 2 / cardano-cli 1.35.3 - linux-x86_64 - ghc-8.10.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You tADA is locked forever. Luckily it is tADA, not real ADA. The preview network will be re-created in a few week anyway (after preprod, which will be reset on October 19th 2022).

Comment: Where did you get the info on the preprod and preview testnets being reset?

Comment: From the IOG's Technical Discord.

Comment: Thanks! I’m on that discord, but can’t find that announcement. Could you maybe give me a link to it? Thanks a lot

Comment: You probably don't see the SPO channels. You need to pick the SPO role in #start-here and they you will see the SPO channels. The announcement is in the #spo-announcements channel.

Comment: Thanks, got it! Little disappointing to learn about it this way as a non-spo developer and testnet user, but thanks for pointing me to it 

Answer (score 0):

The 'always succeeds' means you can send wrong datum/redeemer but the transaction always goes through - always succeeds.

Thus, the fund is not locked forever. Anybody, with the script, can build a transaction to get it back. There is even a warning NOT to use such script in production. Have you tried the latter part of the helios tutorial?

Or, am I missing something?

Comment: An absent datum might make those UTxOs unmoveable though.